# Increment value if another cell is populated vba

Tags: excel, increment, vba

I am trying to create some automatism on my excel database.

In this case increment a value if another cell is populated.

Example:

Start a count starting at A21 if B21 contains a number or text. 
The count will stop if there is no value on the B adjacent cell.

```
         A     B
   21    1     Text 1
   22    2     Text 2
   23    3     Text 3
   24
   25
```

So far I got this:

```
 Sub Macro1()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, cell As Range, mynumber As Long

    Set r1 = Range("B21:B2642")
    Set r2 = Range("A21:A2642")
    mynumber = 1
    For Each cell In r1
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            cell.Value("A21:A2642") = mynumber
            mynumber = mynumber + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Bests

Comment: Please show that you've already put some effort into your problem. SO is glad to help with problems, but isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hope to be more precise now.

Comment: Thank you for providing us with the work of your own! Now, where lies your problem? What does or does not happen if you run your code?

Comment: When I added the target range ("A21:A2642") an error 13 appeared.  Trying to figure out if I am missing a string to tell where the increment value should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with this,

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rw As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

    rw = 2642
    Set rng = Range("B21:B" & rw)

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c <> "" Then
            If c.Row = 21 Then
                c.Offset(, -1) = 1
            Else
                c.Offset(, -1) = c.Offset(-1, -1) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh wow,  that is something interesting but let me see. If I put a value on the 2643 it will still count right? Any way to modify it to stop at B2642 or before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just check if `rw` is equal or greater than 2642 before `Set rng = Range("B21:B" & rw)`

Comment: Thanks you very much everyone.